# Jquery for checkbox doesn't work for model popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

In ModalPopupExtender control I have a checkbox. Once the checkbox is checked, I want the Submit button in the popup to be enabled or else be disabled.

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkUser" TabIndex="0" runat="server" CssClass="cCheckBox" ClientIDMode="Static" onchange="Checked();"/>
```

```js
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function Checked() {
        if(document.getElementById('<%=chkUser.ClientID%>').checked) {
            document.getElementById('<%=btnSubmit.ClientID%>').EnableSubmitButton = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

I'm getting the following error.

> 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: Checked undefined error.

Comment: 'EnableSubmitButton' is not a valid javascript property.

Comment: You manipulate any element attribute, even if it isn't viewable or used by the DOM. @DinoMyte - think of the aria- attributes

Comment: yeah true. I will correct that. The problem is it wont recognize function Checked()

Answer (score 0):

Move this code to the end of body tag

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

  function Checked() {
    if(document.getElementById('<%=chkUser.ClientID%>').checked) {
      document.getElementById('<%=btnSubmit.ClientID%>').disabled = true;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Also you may need to handle checkbox change event.

```
document.getElementById('<%=chkUser.ClientID%>').onchange = Checked;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change on click to `onchange="Checked(this);"`.

```
<asp:CheckBox  onchange="Checked(this);" ID="chkUser" TabIndex="0" runat="server" CssClass="cCheckBox" ClientIDMode="Static"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Checked(ele) {
        document.getElementById('<%=btnSubmit.ClientID%>').disabled = !ele.checked;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: getting same 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'Checked' is undefined. Modal pop extender is the reason? or the source? src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery '`change`' event delegation on the checkbox and use it's property checked to determine if to disable the button or not.

```
$().ready(function(){
      $('#<%=chkUser.ClientID%>').on('change',function(){           
       $('#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID%>').prop("disabled",!$(this).prop("checked"));
      });
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/h712mu20/2/